# Current libraries used to convert html + svg + css to pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, svg

While there are several questions of this type, and is a common problem, I would like to update on the latest libraries with better results.

I have html code (the content of a div) which has several svg, and uses external css and js, included in the html header. I am looking for how to export it to pdf, it can be in PHP or javascript.

Try these alternatives, without good results:

- jspdf (javascript): The result is a pdf (heavy weight), with a single page, of low quality.
- Html2Pdf (php): does not support the svg tag.
- mPDF (php): error with transformations in mpdf\classes\svg.php

What other alternatives do you recommend?

Thanks for your contributions.

**[EDIT 03-06]**

In order to continue using mpdf, I try to convert the svg tag to img. With two different types of graphics I could do it, with good quality.

In the third, it does not generate the image. Some code to understand the method used:

**HTML**

```
<span id="graf_capitanias_ct"></span>
```

Graphic D3 generation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};
var width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#graf_capitanias_ct")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */
var data = [
    { year: "2018", ct: "4", capitanias: "2"},
    { year: "2017", ct: "1", capitanias: "1"},
    { year: "2016", ct: "3", capitanias: "0"},
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["ct", "capitanias"].map(function(valor) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[valor]};
  });
}));

// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["#d25c4d", "#f2b447"];

// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(",d"))
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y cap_ct_axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x cap_ct_axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")    
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });

 // Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Capitan\u00edas";
      case 1: return "Cuerpos t\u00e9cnicos";
    }
  });

// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
</script>
```

**Conversion svg to img**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function convierte_graficos_cap_ct() {
    var html = '';
    var imgscr = '';
    var img = '';
    var attributes = '';

    // css manual
    d3.selectAll('#graf_capitanias_ct svg')
    .style({
        "font": "10px sans-serif",
        "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"
    });
    d3.selectAll('.cap_ct_axis path, .cap_ct_axis line')
    .style({
        "fill": "none",
        "stroke": "#000"
    });
    d3.selectAll('.cap_ct_axis path.domain')
    .style({
        "stroke": "none"
    });
    d3.selectAll('.cap_ct_axis.y .tick line')
    .style({
        "stroke": "#ddd"
    });

    html = $('#graf_capitanias_ct').html();
    imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
    img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'"';
    attributes = $('svg').prop("attributes");
    $.each(attributes, function() {
        img += ' '+this.name+'="'+this.value+'"';
    });
    img += '>';

    $('#graf_capitanias_ct').html(img); 
}
</script>
```

Note that css styles must be added before converting again. It originally takes them from an external css.

As a result, tag img showing "broken", does not convert the svg. It breaks because there is UTF-8 text in the graph (legend). How should that text be changed before converting?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For PDF Generation we currently use [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy), which is a wrapper for [WKHTMLTOPDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).
We use SVG's for diagrams embed into the HTML and they rendered.
Though we did have a few issues with sizing and placement.
We ended up converting the SVG to an image and then encoding it into base64.
Then just added that Base64 to the `<img src="[Base64String]">`

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) works well to pull down these dependancies.

`{
    "require":{ 
        "knplabs/knp-snappy": "^0.4.3",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386": "0.12.x",
        "wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "0.12.x"
    }
}`

A few other options would be:

- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) - FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.
- [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) - mPDF is a PHP library which generates PDF files from UTF-8 encoded HTML. It is based on FPDF and HTML2FPDF with a number of enhancements.
- [dompdf](https://dompdf.github.io/) - dompdf is an HTML to PDF converter. At its heart, dompdf is (mostly) CSS 2.1 compliant HTML layout and rendering engine written in PHP. It is a style-driven renderer: it will download and read external stylesheets, inline style tags, and the style attributes of individual HTML elements. It also supports most presentational HTML attributes.
- [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) - TCPDF is a PHP library for generating PDF documents on-the-fly easily and with a couple of lines. It support customization and a lot of key features when you work with the creation of PDF files.